# How to disable automatical line-cutting in emacs-term?

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs terminal emulator. GNU Emacs 23.2.1 with GNU bash, version 3.00.0(1)-release.
When some command, say grep 1 file.txt prints very long lines, emacs trunkate them to fit the window width.
But it do that right with that lines, so when I copy such line, i get not single long line, but several eaqually-width lines.

For example:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

After echoing it, say with `cat lorem.ipsum`
I get (if i have a 38-character wide terminal):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectet
ur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod t
empor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliqua.
```

And now, if I copy it from the terminal, I will have 4 lines separated with \n characters.
It is very annoying, how to dispose of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I didn't found the answer, but I've wirtten a quick hack for easy pasting such cuts into the term:

```
;; Linearize the last kill-ring entry
(defun make-single-line-in-clipboard ()
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (yank)
    (pop kill-ring)
    (goto-char 0)
    (while (search-forward "\n" nil t)
      (replace-match "" nil t))
    (kill-region (point-min) (point-max))))

;; Paste into terminal the linearized last killed text
(defun paste-into-term-singlelined ()
  (interactive)
  (term-line-mode)
  (make-single-line-in-clipboard)
  (end-of-buffer)
  (clipboard-yank)
  (term-char-mode))
```

And then, the binging for C-y (I use the [multi-term](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm) extension).

```
 (cons "C-y" 'paste-into-term-singlelined)
```